# How can I add a function to change the page 1 of the api results to page 2 and so on, by clicking on a button, with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change the number of the page returned by the API. So I am using an API to get movies and I am using react hooks to do that. I made a separate function to fetch from the API with useEffect, but I don't know how to include the functionality to change the page returned from the API with react hooks.

I have no idea as to how I can do that.

```
class ContactList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        contacts: [],
        per: 2,
        page: 1,
        totalPages: null
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.loadContacts()
    }

    loadContacts = () => {
        const {per, page, contacts} = this.state;
        const url = `https://student-example-api.herokuapp.com/v1/contacts.json?per=${per}&page=${page}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => this.setState({
                contacts: [...contacts, ...json.contacts]
            }));
    }

    loadMore = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            page: prevState.page + 1
        }), this.loadContacts)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="contacts">
                    {
                        this.state.contacts.map(contact => <li key={contact.id}>
                        <Contact {...contact} />
                        </li>)
                    }
                </ul>
                <a onClick={this.loadMore}>Load More</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I only know how to make it work in the classic approach with classes. So to be more clear, what I basically want is to convert this example to hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the functionality you want to do, you need to understand `useState` and `useEffect`. `useState` is very straightforward and `useEffect` is for the component lifecycle methods.

First rule of thumb for using hooks is you cannot nest that hook into conditions. You have to love hooks unconditionally.

Trick: when you convert class component into functional one with hooks, get rid of `this` in your components first.

If you want a heads up for your code. Here how it is.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ContactList = (props) => {
    // see how it declares and set the state
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]); 

    useEffect(() => {
        // for all the lifecycle methods, you can use this.
        loadContacts();
        // return a function for the componentWillUnmount
        return;
    }, [])

    const loadContacts = () => {
        const url = `https://student-example-api.herokuapp.com/v1/contacts.json?per=${per}&page=${page}`;
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => { 
                // setting state
                setContacts([...contacts, json.contacts]);
            });
    }

    return (
        // whatever you want to render...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert your class-based component to a stateless component and after you need to study `useEffect()` in deep because it's in this method that we do side-effects it also to study `useState()`. It making this you get success.